# How to use sub-queries results in a substraction?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have the following queries. How can I perform a subtraction between the results of 2 queries with *"spendamount" ,"winamount"*. When I subtract to  **(spendamount-winamount)** then I get the following error :

> 1054 - Unknown column 'spendamount' in 'field list'

```
SELECT tbl_customers.*,
IFNULL((SELECT sum(win_amount) FROM `tbl_cricket_customer_contests` where customer_id=tbl_customers.id), 0) as winamount,
(SELECT SUM(tcc.entry_fees) as amount FROM tbl_cricket_customer_contests tccc JOIN tbl_cricket_contest_matches tccm ON tccm.id = tccc.match_contest_id JOIN tbl_cricket_contests tcc ON tcc.id = tccm.contest_id WHERE tccc.customer_id = tbl_customers.id ) as spendamount,
(spendamount-winamount)
FROM (`tbl_customers`) 
WHERE `tbl_customers`.`is_deleted` = 'N' 
GROUP BY `tbl_customers`.`id` 
ORDER BY `spendamount` DESC
```

Comment: You can't use aliases in the `SELECT` part of a query

Answer (score 2):

Please rewrite your query to use joins for the sum quantities:

```
SELECT t.*,
    COALESCE(c.win_amount, 0) AS winamount,
    COALESCE(tccc.amount, 0) AS spendamount,
    (COALESCE(tccc.amount, 0) - COALESCE(c.win_amount, 0)) AS diff
FROM tbl_customers t
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT customer_id, SUM(win_amount) AS win_amount
    FROM tbl_cricket_customer_contests
    GROUP BY customer_id
) c
    ON c.customer_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT customer_id, SUM(tcc.entry_fees) as amount
    FROM tbl_cricket_customer_contests tccc
    INNER JOIN tbl_cricket_contest_matches tccm
        ON tccm.id = tccc.match_contest_id
    INNER JOIN tbl_cricket_contests tcc
        ON tcc.id = tccm.contest_id
) tccc
    ON tccc.customer_id = t.id
WHERE
    t.is_deleted = 'N' 
ORDER BY
    spendamount DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks, this query execution time is fast.

Answer (score 1):

use actual expression instead of alias name or you can use subquery

```
select *,spendamount-winamount from 
( 
   SELECT tbl_customers.*,
    IFNULL((SELECT sum(win_amount) FROM `tbl_cricket_customer_contests` where customer_id=tbl_customers.id), 0) as winamount,
    (SELECT SUM(tcc.entry_fees) as amount FROM tbl_cricket_customer_contests tccc JOIN tbl_cricket_contest_matches tccm ON tccm.id = tccc.match_contest_id JOIN tbl_cricket_contests tcc ON tcc.id = tccm.contest_id WHERE tccc.customer_id = tbl_customers.id ) as spendamount
    FROM (`tbl_customers`) 
    WHERE `tbl_customers`.`is_deleted` = 'N' 

)A
```

Comment: Same queries repeat that's  not right way speed is slow.

Comment: then you can use subquery @Kheteshkumawat

Comment: I don't see the point of using `GROUP BY` in your query, since the subqueries already do the aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

please try this query.

```
SELECT AA.*,AA.spendamount - AA.winamount As Amount FROM 
(
SELECT tbl_customers.*,
IFNULL((SELECT sum(win_amount) FROM `tbl_cricket_customer_contests` where customer_id=tbl_customers.id), 0) as winamount,
(SELECT SUM(tcc.entry_fees) as amount FROM tbl_cricket_customer_contests tccc JOIN tbl_cricket_contest_matches tccm ON tccm.id = tccc.match_contest_id JOIN tbl_cricket_contests tcc ON tcc.id = tccm.contest_id WHERE tccc.customer_id = tbl_customers.id ) as spendamount,
(spendamount-winamount)
FROM (`tbl_customers`) 
WHERE `tbl_customers`.`is_deleted` = 'N' 
GROUP BY `tbl_customers`.`id` 
ORDER BY `spendamount` DESC
)As AA
```

Comment: What is the point of even using `GROUP BY` in your query, given that the subqueries are already doing all the aggregation work?